# Best database software in a standalone program in flash?

Tags: database, flash, installation

i just made a standalone game in flash and it has a user interface (stores the name and scores of the user). what is the best database software in a standalone program that i can use. and how can i make it an installer so that i can give it to my friends. thanks

Comment: do you know a site or tutorials about how to make csv file from actionscript 3.0 and how can actionscript reads this types of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try PostgreSQL (it's free), but you should consider if you really need a database.

Based on the description you have provided it seems to be a bit overkill if you just want to store the user's names and scores.

It would probably be easier to just write the scores to a file (such as a comma-separated list (CSV) file).

Comment: do you know a site or tutorials about how to make csv file from actionscript 3.0 and how can actionscript reads this types of data?